# Derived store firing when other properties change

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have a store which contains a number of properties for a form submission:

```js
const store = writable({
    network: {
        content: "",
        error: ""
    },
    name: {
        content: "",
        error: ""
    }
};
```

I'd like some checks to only be fired when one of the parent properties children have been changed. So I created a derived store for each:

```js
const networkStore = derived(store, ($store) => $store.network);
networkStore.subscribe((network) => {
  console.log('network handler fired');
});

const nameStore = derived(store, ($store) => $store.name);
nameStore.subscribe((name) => {
  console.log('name handler fired');
});
```

However, both of these callbacks get fired when any of the data is modified. The only way I've found to isolate an event is to create a derived store on a specific value property (eg. a property with a string value, rather than its parent object).

```js
const nameStore = derived(store, ($store) => $store.name.content);
nameStore.subscribe((nameContent) => {
  console.log('nameContent handler fired');
});
```

The above example will fire only when the `$store.name.content` property is modified.

My question is, is there a way to subscribe to partial objects of a larger object, and have that callback fired only when properties in that sub-object are modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that that is possible. However, in my experience it is better anyway to keep writables as simple as possible, and then create the big and complex objects as derived.
So in your case, think about making nameStore and networkStore to writables, this way you can subscribe to them individually, like you asked for in your question. And for the case that you need the whole store, you can just create a derived called store from those two writables.

Comment: I hadn't considered that (making simple writables and composing them with derived). At first glance that seems like it could be a much better approach, thanks!